# Can't install pycurl or wptools with pip

Tags: python, pip

I cannot get python to install pycurl or wptools on my windows computer.

I get the same error when trying to install for these both packages from cmd.

I've looked extensively in stackoverflow and other forums and I see lot's of people are having the same problem but very few ways to fix it.

my Python version:

```
 C:\Users\crist>python
 Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

---

```
C:\Users\crist>pip install wptools

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ofsbmmel\pycurl\
```

Comment: There are no prebuilt wheels available for Python 3.7 on Windows yet. Either switch to Python 3.6, or [build `pycurl` from source](https://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#building-from-source).

Comment: I switched to Python 3.6 and it worked! Thanks!!